# How can I use ROS with arduino robot?

Tags: ros, arduino, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an arduino robot and a Raspberry Pi.

I note that there is a package called ROS arduino. How can I develop a ROS driver to control my arduino robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224993/how-can-i-use-ros-with-arduino-robot?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

You should use rosserial_arduino package;
It has a lot of tutorials and can be easily extended:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0